# Any way to get bsearch to consistently do equality matching?

Tags: arrays, ruby, bsearch

As with [the sample array from the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Array.html#method-i-bsearch), passing an equality returns inconsistent results:

```
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch{ |x| x == 4}  # => nil
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch{ |x| x == 7}  # => 7
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch{ |x| x == 10} # => nil
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch{ |x| x == 12} # => 12
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch{ |x| x == 0}  # => nil
```

As the docs show, you can get the correct result with `>=`; however you also get:

```
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch {|x| x >= 6 } #=> 7
```

which is not what you want when you're looking specifically for `6`. How do you get it to return consistent results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Array.html#method-i-bsearch), to use bsearch, your array must be sorted with respect to the block.

Looking at your block results mapped out, `[false, false, true, false, false]` is not sorted.

Your block is currently set up to use *find-minimum* mode, because it returns `true`/`false`. Instead, try using *find-any* mode, with a block that returns `-1`/`0`/`1`.

```
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch {|x| 7 <=> x } # => 7
[0, 4, 7, 10, 12].bsearch {|x| 6 <=> x } # => nil
```

In this case, we use the "comparator" or "spaceship" operator (`<=>`), which returns `-1`/`0`/`1`.